# What component to use to create a twitter timeline like list on wxwidgets?

Tags: listview, wxwidgets

I'm new to wxWidgets, so sorry if the terminology is off or I am asking something obvious, please point me in the right way.

I am creating a client app for a web service I have created, and I would like to show the information on some list type UI, only I want it to be a single columned row that contains several pieces of information, an image, dates, several texts in certain places.

So, is there

1. Some extension library that can do this
2. Customize wxListCtrl or some other existing library and inherit from that

I am not using any form builder tools, just directly coding in coordinates and sizes in the code.

**Edit:**

Here is what I have done right now,

on the Constructor,

```
m_timeline = new wxListCtrl( this, wxID_ANY, wxPoint( -1, 30), wxSize( 950, 600 ), wxLC_REPORT );

m_timeline->InsertColumn(0, _("icon"));
m_timeline->InsertColumn(1, _("post_owner"));
m_timeline->InsertColumn(2, _("body), wxLIST_FORMAT_LEFT, 700);
```

then when needed,

```
wxListItem tweet;
note.SetId(i);

m_noteTimeline->InsertItem( i, tweet );
m_noteTimeline->SetItem( i, 0, xxxxx);
m_noteTimeline->SetItem( i, 1, xxxxx );
m_noteTimeline->SetItem( i, 2, xxxx );
```

I'm not saying this doesn't work, but its not exactly what I have in mind, mainly because,

1. I would rather have a single column with all the information
2. This implementation would not allow each row to have buttons to it( if it was a twitter client, it would need to have a reply button, delete and the like)
3. The text to be put in body can be multiline, and it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

You also could try to use [wxHtmlListBox](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_html_list_box.html) (possibly in virtual mode) if you need each piece of data in list item to be displayed with special font/style.

Comment: We miss you T-Rex in wxwidgets forum and your great tutorials!

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, wxListCtrl will do what you need without needing any customization.  Have you tried it?  What problem did you hit?

If you want a collection of different widgets, such as buttons, in you your column, then I suggest the simplest thing would be to use a single column wxFlexGridSizer.

Comment: After looking at the references and googling that wxListCtrl could only have a single piece of data on each column it, not being able to say, have a string with a name on the upper left, datetime on the upper right, an icon to the left, buttons here, that kind of stuff, that and it doesn't seem to be able tp handle multiline strings was discouraging.